# CardView in NestedScrollView increases elevation automatically [Image included]

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-cardview, android-elevation, nestedscrollview

I'm adding cards in a nested scrollview. The card elevation automatically increases for the cards that are lower down the order in the LinearLayout. To understand the issue, notice the card elevation between first and last cards. The last card has a darker shadow than the first one, though the cards are same. How to resolve?

Using appcompat v7:22.+ as dependency for v7 library.

This is my card view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hint"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="ABC"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/textHint"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="DEFG BHJHKJ"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is how I'm using the card view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <include
                layout="@layout/shared_activity_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f3f3f3"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                <include
                android:id="@+id/date"
                layout="@layout/custom_detail_item_card" />
                <include
                android:id="@+id/confirmation"
                layout="@layout/custom_detail_item_card" />
                <include
                android:id="@+id/admit"
                layout="@layout/custom_detail_item_card" />

                <include
                android:id="@+id/meeting_point"
                layout="@layout/custom_detail_item_card" />



                <include
                android:id="@+id/pickup_time"
                layout="@layout/custom_detail_item_card" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/dropoff_time"
                layout="@layout/custom_detail_item_card" />

                <include
                android:id="@+id/cancellation"
                layout="@layout/custom_detail_item_card" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!--</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>-->
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkfNO.jpg

Comment: Hello, I have a similar issue currently. Were you able to solve that issue ?

Comment: @Bialy No. I couldn't

Comment: It seems like it's the normal behavior of cardViews inside scrollable views (scrolls, lists, etc). Check out some official Google apps and you will find out they have the same behavior. It's like an elevation increasing factor as the cardView is farther from the top of the screen.

Comment: Hello, I have a similar issue currently. Were you able to solve that issue ?